# How to add new headers to http requests methods in Java?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I need to implement special headers to the request in my server (and some new responses too). Let's say something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
My-header-goes-here: example-value
```

As you can see, I want to extend standard version of **GET** by **My-header-goes-here**. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What HTTP client are you using? Did you check its documentation?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't decided yet.. What do you propose?

Comment: But I suppose, I should use "pure Java" in this project

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("myserver.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("My-header-goes-here", "example-value");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(16000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(16000);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(json);
        out.close();

        return connection.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Can I reach the same using sockets?